# Jenkins Plugins Install Issue

Tags: ssl, jenkins

I am trying to install the version 2.162 of the open source Jenkins. The Jenkins successfully came up but, when I go to Manage Jenkins-> Manage Plugins, I see following error:

> There were errors checking the update sites: SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I know I need to add a certificate but not sure from which website, I can add the certificate from.

Can anyone help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your network ssl certificate to your jre cacerts.

**NOTE:**

1. Confirm you are installing certificate to jre which is used by jenkins
2. You are installing certificate in cacerts file of JRE only NOT JVM cacerts.
3. You are installing root certificate i.e. top most in hierarchy not any of its children.
4. if you still get PKIX for other URLs(After solving one url problem) repeat this process of installing root certificate of all of the URLs present in Log with PKIX.

**Step 1 : Get certificate.**

1. Open https://repo.maven.apache.org URL using chrome browser.
2. Click on view certificate
3. select Top most certificate on chain and drag and drop to desktop.
   [image]

**Step 2 : install certificate to cacerts**

*you can use any method to get jre path of Jenkins I am using same jre for all of the applications so i am using MVN command to make it very simple. skip step 1 and 2 bellow if you know JRE path or your configuration is different.*

1. open command prompt or terminal and type command

> mvn -version

2. Grab path to jre which would be shown to your after typing above command.
3. Download [this](http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) tool.
   OR
   You may use following command to install certificate

```
    keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias <AliasName> -file <certificate> -keystore <KeystoreFile> -storepass <Password>
```

4. select open option in that tool and navigate to that path which you grabbed at point 2. Now you are at jre folder. Open lib folder. Open security folder.(YOURMAVENJDKPATH/jre/lib/security/cacerts)
5. Select cacerts file located in that security folder.Now you can see all the certificates in that tool. **Tool would ask for password enter "changeit"(without double quote string changeit is the password)**
6. find out import certificate icon and click on it.
7. Select the certificate which you downloaded in step 1.
8. Save your changes and close the tool.

Now your problem is resolved.